# Can Trusted Web Activitity apps work on Huawei phones?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, huawei-mobile-services, trusted-web-activity

I am working on publishing a progressive web app (PWA) in Google Play, as a Trusted Web Activity (TWA). I packaged my app using bubblewrap, as instructed in the official docs: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/trusted-web-activity/

All went smoothly. I tested the app on a handful of Android phones, among them two Huawei phones, both with gapps (google services, google play, ...): Huawei P9, and Huawei P30. On both of them, the TWA is unusable.

The behavior is as follows:

1. Install the TWA app from google play
2. Close all running apps
3. Open the TWA app -> It is stuck on the app splash screen
4. Close all running apps
5. Open Chrome, then go back to home screen, and open the TWA app -> It works, but address bar is showing (it is not showing on other phone models)

Installing the PWA from Chrome browser menu works fine (as PWA, without Google Play / bubblewrap / TWA in game).

I know that Huawei phones are less common in the western world now, but I am still wondering if other developers ran into the same problem, and whether there is a way to make TWAs work on Huawei phones.

Comment: @hydrant I tried to reproduce your problem by downloading a TWA app off the Google Play Store and running it on a Huawei P30 (ELE-L29), but it works fine for me using the steps you described. Do you have more information like what app you downloaded from Google Play?

Comment: @Zinna Interesting. It is this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=genuinegrowth.ark.twa . I wonder if it is something in the manifest / the way the TWA is built, that makes  it being stuck.